# Is it possible to load observable changes in chunks with ngrx

Tags: angular, rxjs, ngrx

I am observing a collection of items which is filterable. Right now I only have about 600 elements.

Whenever all 600 are selected there is lag during rendering to actually redraw these components.

I want to know if it is possible to observe the changes in the collection but to only take a chunk of the elements at a time until the whole collection is loaded.

---

Since an example was asked for here is my current selection.

The observable

```
this.temperatures$ = this.store.select(state => state.weatherState.filteredTemperatures);
```

The template

```
<mat-accordion>
    <div *ngFor="let temp of temperatures$ | async">
        ...
    </div>
</mat-accordion>
```

Comment: you need to at least add some examples with in particular the code where this observable would be used.

Comment: @VictorNoël Sure. I've added the example, it is however completely bare-bones so I honestly didn't see the need.

Comment: thx, one more question: when you say "until the whole collection is loaded" what do you mean? I ask because when you do the `store.select` you get an observable that gives you the whole collection at once.

Comment: @VictorNoël What I mean is that if I have 600 items in a list I would like to have them returned in chunks, so instead of being given 600 I see something like 100, 200, 300 ... until I get the entire list back. The idea is that this will stop 600 items being redrawn at once.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not saying that's a good idea to render the 600 elements and should probably use some pagination.

BUT, rendering 600 elements shouldn't be a problem I think.

First, split your code into 2 components, let say `list` and `item`.

From where you want to draw the list, instead of doing:

```
<mat-accordion>
    <div *ngFor="let temp of temperatures$ | async">
        ...
    </div>
</mat-accordion>
```

Call the list component like that:

```
<mat-accordion>
  <list [list]="temperatures$ | async"></list>
</mat-accordion>
```

As you're using ngrx, I assume that this list is immutable and thus, set your `list` component with a `ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush`.

As long as the list is not modified, Angular won't check all the bindings to it on every change detection.

Second, make sure your list is not completely redraw. 
Use `trackBy` on your `ngFor`.

So, from the `list` component, you now have access to a list (and not an observable). You can do:

HTML:

```
<div *ngFor="let item of list; trackBy: trackByFn">
  <item [item]="item"></item>
</div>
```

TS (in your component class):

```
trackByFn(index, item) {
  // return something unique from your item, probably its ID
  return item.id;
}
```

And finally, don't forget to set your item component to OnPush too.

Let me know if perfs are ok after that :)

Comment: I appreciate you trying to solve the deeper issue here, which is rendering 600 items at once, however I plan to resolve this by implementing a virtual list. I don't think this particular suggestion is going to work as the list can go from something like 30 items to 600 items based on a single filter change, so the list will undergo a full redraw.